# How can I change the colors of the slices in pie charts in plotly for r using hexadecimal strings?

Tags: r, pie-chart, plotly

This is my pie chart as of right now:

```
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)


P <- data.frame (labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
             values = c(5, 8, 3, 4, 9))

plot_ly(P, labels = labels, values = values, type = "pie",
    marker = list(colors=c("lightskyblue", "deepblue", "dodgerblue", "midnightblue", "powderblue")),
    textinfo="value",
    textposition="outside")
```

I wanted to change its colors with hexidecimal strings so I could use palettes from RColorBrewer. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put the hex values into the strings, preceded with a hash (pound symbol) `#`. the first two digits in hex are for red, the next 2 for green, then 2 digits for blue (#RRGGBB).  Optionally you can add an extra two digits for the alpha (transparency) (#RRGGBBAA).

e.g

```
plot_ly(P, labels = labels, values = values, type = "pie",
    marker = list(colors=c("#556677", "#AA3344", "#772200", 
                           "#11AA22", "#AA231B88")), # the last color has alpha value set.
    textinfo="value",
    textposition="outside")
```

Answer (score 3):

Exploring `RColorBrewer` package

```
   library(RColorBrewer)
```

To see list of functions inside RColorBrewer package

```
   ls("package:RColorBrewer")
   #  [1] "brewer.pal"         "brewer.pal.info"    "display.brewer.all"
   #  [4] "display.brewer.pal"
```

To display all color schemes

```
   display.brewer.all()
```

To get the Blues hexadecimal strings

```
   brewer.pal(9,"Blues")
   # [1] "#F7FBFF" "#DEEBF7" "#C6DBEF" "#9ECAE1" "#6BAED6" "#4292C6" "#2171B5"
   # [8] "#08519C" "#08306B"

   brewer.pal(10,"Blues")
   # [1] "#F7FBFF" "#DEEBF7" "#C6DBEF" "#9ECAE1" "#6BAED6" "#4292C6" "#2171B5"
   # [8] "#08519C" "#08306B"
   # Warning message:
   # In brewer.pal(10, "Blues") :
   # n too large, allowed maximum for palette Blues is 9
   # Returning the palette you asked for with that many colors
```

To View the Blues palatte

```
  display.brewer.pal(9,"Blues")
```

There are limits on the number of colours you can get, but if you want to extend the Sequential or Diverging groups you can do so with the colorRampPalatte command, for example :

```
  colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,”Blues”))(100)
```

Example for `divergent`, `qualitative` and `sequential` schemes. The `Spectral`, `Set2` , `Reds`, these names can be seen using command mentioned above `display.brewer.all()`. You can use some other schemes from the list.

```
 display.brewer.pal(4,"Spectral")
 brewer.pal(4,"Spectral")
 # [1] "#D7191C" "#FDAE61" "#ABDDA4" "#2B83BA"

 display.brewer.pal(4,"Set2")
 brewer.pal(4,"Set2")
 # [1] "#66C2A5" "#FC8D62" "#8DA0CB" "#E78AC3"

 display.brewer.pal(4,"Reds")
 brewer.pal(4,"Reds")
 # [1] "#FEE5D9" "#FCAE91" "#FB6A4A" "#CB181D"
```